# the company that is owned by X / the company X owns

Tags: relative-clauses

> What’s the name of the company **that is owned by him** in the EU?
>
> What’s the name of the company **he owns** in the EU?

If I understand correctly, both sentences are idiomatic but the first one is more formal. The meaning is the same. If I change the pronoun "he" to "ABC Bank", the second sentence (the relative clause) will sound good only in informal speaking or also in formal writing?

Comment: Only the second one sounds idiomatic to me.  I think it's because the ending of first one sounds like "him in the EU" owns the company, which makes you backtrack.  I'll have to think more about the "ABC Bank"  situation - this is a good question.

Comment: The first is definitely not "more formal". The second one is better writing. Avoid passives unless necessary.

Comment: You could simply say "What's the name of his company?" or "What's his company called?". The passive doesn't necessarily make a statement formal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passives should be avoided if not needed:

What’s the name of the company that is owned by him in the EU? [not needed]
because the sentence below is better:

**What’s the name of the company he owns in the EU**?

Another example: ***I drove the car he owns***.
NOT: **I drove the car owned by him**.

**NOT because of the grammar** which is fine, but because the other form is simpler. Fewer words, more concise.

Comment: I upvoted the answer, but want to add that there are also subtle constraints on the English passive.  For instance, "I drove the car that was bought (by him) yesterday" is much more acceptable, since you can easily delete the reference to the agent and you are describing an event.  On the other hand, you can't idiomatically say "I drove the car that was owned," except in very limited situations.  All this can be avoided by simply using the active voice of the verb, where there are no limitations.

Comment: You can't change the sentence by removing he owns or owned by him without changing the meaning. It would become something else. So, for me, your comment does not make sense here.

Comment: That was the intent of my comment.  The fact that you cannot remove it in this case, but can in others, means there is something not quite transparent about the structure "owned by him."